# Mapbox GL Js: adding and removing GeoJSON sources and layers

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Im having a problems adding and removing layers in mapbox gl.

I have this layer:

```
   map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8
        }
    });
```

then I remove it by doing:

```
map.removeLayer('route')
```

Everything works fine.

However when trying to add the same layer again I get the following error:

```
Error: There is already a source with this ID
```

Even though I'm adding a Layer. I don't know how to get the source removed because the source does not have an ID.

My final result is to be able to add and remove this layer by clicking on a button.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just found out that the source is created with the same id as in the layer so:

```
map.removeSource('route')
```

Worked perfectly to completely remove both the layer and source.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I edited & added the extra step of `map.removeLayer()`.  If I just performed a `map.removeSource()` first, then Mapbox GL JS threw this error `Error: "Source "route" cannot be removed while layer "route" is using it."`

Comment: Then remove that layer and reinit it after add new layer.

Answer (score 17):

You should remove layer first then remove its source.

```js
map.removeLayer(id);
map.removeSource(id);
```

in your case `id = 'route'`.

Answer (score 15):

...and check that the source/layer exist before you try to remove them

```
if (map.getLayer(id)) {
  map.removeLayer(id);
}
if (map.getSource(id)) {
  map.removeSource(id);
}
```